# pyExcelerator and utf8?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, pyexcelerator

I have <s>stolen</s> found the following code on stackoverflow (but forgot where, sorry):

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import string
import sys
import getopt
import re
import os
import os.path
import csv
from pyExcelerator import *

def usage():
  """ Display the usage """
  print "Usage: " + sys.argv[0] + " [OPTIONS] csvfile"
  print "OPTIONS:"
  print "--title|-t: If set, the first line is the title line"
  print "--lines|-l n: Split output into files of n lines or less each"
  print "--sep|-s c [def:,] : The character to use for field delimiter"
  print "--output|o : output file name/pattern"
  print "--help|h : print this information"
  sys.exit(2)

def openExcelSheet(outputFileName):
  """ Opens a reference to an Excel WorkBook and Worksheet objects """
  workbook = Workbook()
  worksheet = workbook.add_sheet("Sheet 1")
  return workbook, worksheet

def writeExcelHeader(worksheet, titleCols):
  """ Write the header line into the worksheet """
  cno = 0
  for titleCol in titleCols:
    worksheet.write(0, cno, titleCol)
    cno = cno + 1

def writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, columns):
  """ Write a non-header row into the worksheet """
  cno = 0
  for column in columns:
    worksheet.write(lno, cno, column)
    cno = cno + 1

def closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName):
  """ Saves the in-memory WorkBook object into the specified file """
  workbook.save(outputFileName)

def getDefaultOutputFileName(inputFileName):
  """ Returns the name of the default output file based on the value
      of the input file. The default output file is always created in
      the current working directory. This can be overriden using the
      -o or --output option to explicitly specify an output file """
  baseName = os.path.basename(inputFileName)
  rootName = os.path.splitext(baseName)[0]
  return string.join([rootName, "xls"], '.')

def renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno):
  """ Renames the output file name by appending the current file number
      to it """
  dirName, baseName = os.path.split(outputFileName)
  rootName, extName = os.path.splitext(baseName)
  backupFileBaseName = string.join([string.join([rootName, str(fno)], '-'), extName], '')
  backupFileName = os.path.join(dirName, backupFileBaseName)
  try:
    os.rename(outputFileName, backupFileName)
  except OSError:
    print "Error renaming output file:", outputFileName, "to", backupFileName, "...aborting"
    sys.exit(-1)

def validateOpts(opts):
  """ Returns option values specified, or the default if none """
  titlePresent = False
  linesPerFile = -1
  outputFileName = ""
  sepChar = ","
  for option, argval in opts:
    if (option in ("-t", "--title")):
      titlePresent = True
    if (option in ("-l", "--lines")):
      linesPerFile = int(argval)
    if (option in ("-s", "--sep")):
      sepChar = argval
    if (option in ("-o", "--output")):
      outputFileName = argval
    if (option in ("-h", "--help")):
      usage()
  return titlePresent, linesPerFile, sepChar, outputFileName

def main():
  """ This is how we are called """
  try:
    opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "tl:s:o:h", ["title", "lines=", "sep=", "output=", "help"])
  except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
  if (len(args) != 1):
    usage()
  inputFileName = args[0]
  try:
    inputFile = open(inputFileName, 'r')
  except IOError:
    print "File not found:", inputFileName, "...aborting"
    sys.exit(-1)
  titlePresent, linesPerFile, sepChar, outputFileName = validateOpts(opts)
  if (outputFileName == ""):
    outputFileName = getDefaultOutputFileName(inputFileName)
  workbook, worksheet = openExcelSheet(outputFileName)
  fno = 0
  lno = 0
  titleCols = []
  reader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=sepChar)
  for line in reader:
    if (lno == 0 and titlePresent):
      if (len(titleCols) == 0):
        titleCols = line
      writeExcelHeader(worksheet, titleCols)
    else:
      writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, line)
    lno = lno + 1
    if (linesPerFile != -1 and lno >= linesPerFile):
      closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName)
      renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno)
      fno = fno + 1
      lno = 0
      workbook, worksheet = openExcelSheet(outputFileName)
  inputFile.close()
  closeExcelSheet(workbook, outputFileName)
  if (fno > 0):
    renameOutputFile(outputFileName, fno)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

My problem is, when using it to convert a utf8 file (containing e.g. 'LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE' (U+00F3) "ó"), it produces the byte sequence 0x43 0x04, which is rendered by both open office and ms excel as a "y" (0x43, while just dropping the 0x04).

does anyone know what I or pyExcelerator are doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manually encode/decode data from utf-8 file:

```
reader = csv.reader(inputFile, delimiter=sepChar)
for line in reader:
  if (lno == 0 and titlePresent):
    if (len(titleCols) == 0):
      titleCols = line
    writeExcelHeader(worksheet, titleCols)
  else:
    # writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, line)
    # in unicode function source file encoding should be passed
    writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in line])


def writeExcelRow(worksheet, lno, columns):
  """ Write a non-header row into the worksheet """
  cno = 0
  for column in columns:
    #worksheet.write(lno, cno, column)
    worksheet.write(lno, cno, column.encode('utf-8'))
    cno = cno + 1
```

Check examples here (unicode_csv_reader, utf_8_encoder): http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

Comment: but the output shall also contain the unicode sequences, wouldn't this convert them? or does writeExcelRow detect unicode but not utf8, and handle this one correctly?

Comment: I'll try this one and report back soon.

Comment: tried, now i get: http://pastebin.com/SP2tmk2E, does that mean my input isn't utf8? but that can't be, I'm just pulling it from a utf8-collated mysql table and binary writing it to csv in a php script

Comment: @nonchip hm, seems that you have not utf-8 in csv, try with `latin1`: `[unicode(cell, 'latin1') for cell in line]`

Comment: thanks, it was really my apache enforcing latin1, while both the output xls and input mysql table were utf8, your code fixed it now.